# Nonblocking webserver on .Net for Comet applications

Tags: .net, python, ironpython, comet

I am trying to implement a Comet style (e.g. chat) application using IronPython.  While I don't need to scale to twitter like dimensions, it is vital that the response time is lightening fast.  All the possibilities in Python ([Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), [Magnum-Py](http://code.google.com/p/magnum-py/)) do not work with IronPython, often because of epoll support.

Is there a default choice in the .Net world for comet style applications? Or a pure python implementation with long-pulling support? I have tried [NTornado](http://ntornado.codeplex.com/), but performance is currently very poor (100-1000x slower than Tornado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is. Check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a full comet solution for .NET/IIS. To my knowledge, it's the only full implementation of comet for .NET available today. You can use the on-demand version for free (up to a limit), or pick up the server version to host it yourself. It's pretty inexpensive too, no runtime fees, etc.